# Passing values in query string in jsp and struts

Tags: java, jsp, struts, query-string, encode

I am passing below value which has special characters in query string to an action class.On hitting the action class the param1 value breaks and only empty. pdf is being passed in the url. I want to pass the entire string. How to achieve it?

```
<TD><A href=javascript:openWindow("lookuptest.do?action=download&param1=<%=test%>")><%="Download"%></a></TD>
```

where test value is `empty.pdf@error.pdf@test.pdf`

Comment: there are misplaced double quotes try this.. may be it's not solution.. <TD><A href=javascript:openWindow("lookuptest.do?action=download&param1='empty.pdf@error.pdf@test.pdf'")><%="Download"%></a></TD>

Comment: if you are on windows then you can use double quotes if you have long names and remove characters that aren't supported.

Answer (score 1):

There is a missing double quote. 
If `param1` value is hardcoded then try it in following way:

```
 href=javascript:openWindow("lookuptest.do?action=download&param1=empty.pdf@error.pdf@test.pdf")
```

Comment: My statements looks like this

Answer (score 0):

```
href=javascript:openWindow("lookuptest.do?action=download&param1=URLEncoder.encode(empty.pdf@error.pdf@test.pdf)")
```

This worked for me